# openlayers additive opacity does not render equally

Tags: html, openlayers

I recently integrated the [scriptaculous slider](http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/slider/) with a few similar layers to acheive a 'tween' effect between the layers.

As the slider is dragged, the layers opacity is altered. There are never more than 2 layers visible at any one time and at the intersecting points, only one layer is visible.

The total opacity for the two (or one) visible layers is always 0.63, so the layers will be allocated a portion of that for their individual opacity level ie at one point, layerA=0.1 and layerB=0.53.

The layers are all solid colours and in many cases, the same colour covers the same area for all of layers.

As far as the math is concerned, my implementation is perfect.

The **problem** is that while the total opacity for the 2 layers remains at 0.63, the visual transparency for the combination fluctuates. As the midpoint between 2 layers is reached, the combined visual transparency increases.

This gives a flickering effect while the slider is dragged.

Essentially, if `a` and `b` are both solid red visible layers over a baselayer, my observation is that:

```
a.opacity=0.31 + b.opacity=0.32 < a.opacity=0.01 + b.opacity=0.62
```

I have tested this on chrome and firefox with identical results.

Is this an openlayers, javascript or renderer issue and is there a alternative approach?